# Do I need volatile when timing a piece of code?

Tags: c++, volatile, timing

I want to auto-tune my code and for that must measure the time required by some section of code, for example

```
auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
section_of_code_to_be_timed(arguments);
auto dt = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>
         (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()-t0).counts();
// ... using dt to tweak auto-tuning parameters
```

What I worry about is that the compiler may re-arrange the calls to `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()` and `section_of_code_to_be_timed()`, whereby invalidating my timing measurement. Is this a valid worry? If so, can I prevent it with declaring `t0` `volatile` or otherwise (how)?

(I noticed that I could use the RAII idiom, similar to `std::lock_guard`, which doesn't seem to use `volatile`...)

Comment: I don't think it can do that because the timer function is an external call and the compiler doesn't "know" its consequence or structure, so it won't move it. The potential problem is that `section_of_code` can be removed if it does absolute nothing for example only manipulating data on the stack and returning. Lastly, I haven't seen this be a problem in practice. Also use a profiler like kcachegrind.

Comment: @Mikhail I'm **not profiling** my code (as it clear from the Q). `section_of_code_to_be_timed` is not empty and cannot be optimised away. The performance of `section_of_code_to_be_timed()` depends on run-time parameters and I cannot profile all possible value combinations. Hence, I want to use auto-tuning.

Comment: Out of curiosity, for which platform are you doing such cleverness on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formally, or practically?  Formally, the calls to
`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()` aren't observable
behavior, so the compiler can rearange them any way it wants.
Practically, compilers will treat them as observable behavior,
so you won't have any problems on this score.  On the other
hand, you'd better do something to ensure that
`section_of_code_to_be_timed` actually does something.  (I often
make it a virtual member of a class, which introduces enough
indirection to fool most compilers.  And in the function itself,
I ensure that it produces a result which will be visible outside
of the function.)

Note that either way, `volatile` is irrelevant.  About all it
ensures is that `t0` and `dt` are written in the correct order
(and in practice, it often won't ensure that); it makes no
guarantees about `section_of_code_to_be_timed` with respect to
`t0` or `dt`.

Comment: ` Formally, the calls to std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() aren't observable behavior` Is this true? If it calls a system routine or executes some inline ASM doesn't that count as observable behavior the same way a `cout` does?

Comment: @Mikhail I seem to remember some point in the past where all system calls (and there must be system call underlying `std::chrono::high_resolution::clock::now()`) were considered observable behavior, but the current standard only refers to data written into a file.  (On the other hand: if he outputs `dt`, moving code around could certainly affect that output.  But I don't think this counts; any optimization could also affect the output, and traditionally, execution times have _not_ been considered observable, even if users can clearly see them.)

Answer (score 1):

Use volatile to control access to unusual memory locations (such as hardware registers), where every read and write must happen in the order specified by the program. A normal variable, atomic or otherwise, doesn't usually require such control.

The two concepts are unrelated to each other. In particular, do not confuse volatile with a keyword used in other languages to make variables atomic. In C++, volatile has nothing to do with thread interactions whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

You could insert a "compiler barrier": unfortunately, such constructs are not standard.

Under gcc (and clang?) `__asm__ __volatile__ ("" ::: "memory")` will act as a full barrier (note: a compiler barrier is *not* a memory barrier).

I don't have it handy, but http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f20w0x5e.aspx indicates that `_ReadWriteBarrier();` should give a similar effect under VC++ (although it is deprecated). Other compilers may or may not support their own equivalents.

Finally C++11 does provide `atomic_signal_fence`, which looks promising, but it isn't clear to me whether it does the right thing.